# How to convert the string with Byte to byte array in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string with byte format in it as below

```
var string="22-74-68-64-62-32-75-74-71-53-5A-6D-44-32-65-61-38-39-43-6A-39-4A-41-3D-3D-22"
```

Convert this to byte array as

```
byte[] arr=[22-74-68-64-62-32-75-74-71-53-5A-6D-44-32-65-61-38-39-43-6A-39-4A-41-3D-3D-22]
```

Comment: If one of these answers solves your problem, best mark one as accepted for future readers

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more succinct with [`Convert.ToByte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToByte_System_String_System_Int32_)

```
var bytes = input.Split('-')
                 .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x,16))
                 .ToArray();
```

**Additional resources**

[ToByte(String, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToByte_System_String_System_Int32_)

> Converts the string representation of a number in a **specified base** to
>   an equivalent 8-bit unsigned integer.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "22-74-68-64-62-32-75-74-71-53-5A-6D-44-32-65-61-38-39-43-6A-39-4A-41-3D-3D-22";

        //Split string by '-'
        string[] spl = input.Split('-');

        //Parse bytes and add them to a list
        List<byte> buf = new List<byte>();
        foreach(string s in spl) {
            buf.Add(byte.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
        }

        //Convert list to byte[]
        byte[] bytes = buf.ToArray();

        //Print byte[] into console
        foreach(byte b in bytes)
            Console.WriteLine(b.ToString("X2"));
    }
}
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HZCsBP)

The above code will cause an exception if the input is not a perfect string of bytes delimited by dashes. If you're not expecting a perfect input you'll have to use `byte.TryParse` like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "22-74-68-64-62-32-75-74-71-53-5A-XX-wrgererh-6D-44-32-65-61-38-39-43-6A-39-4A-41-3D-3D-22";

        //Split string by '-'
        string[] spl = input.Split('-');

        //Parse bytes and add them to a list
        List<byte> buf = new List<byte>();
        byte tb;
        foreach(string s in spl) {
            if(byte.TryParse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out tb))
                buf.Add(tb);
        }

        //Convert list to byte[]
        byte[] bytes = buf.ToArray();

        //Print byte[] into console
        foreach(byte b in bytes)
            Console.WriteLine(b.ToString("X2"));
    }
}
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/39I7V5)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Linq` to get it quite tidy

```
byte[] arr = input.Split('-').Select(i => byte.Parse(i, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();
```